# VBA connects to the SAP GUI, but not to SAP NW Business Client 5

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I use following lines of code to connect VBA to a SAP GUI session and it works well:

```
Sub Change_date()

Dim SapGuiAuto
Dim SetApp
Dim Connection
Dim Session

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SetApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SetApp.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
'And so on.
```

However this doesn't work in the SAP GUI inside SAP NetWeaver Business Client 5.

SAP GUI:
[image: SAP GUI]

SAP GUI inside SAP NW Business Client 5:
[image: SAP GUI inside SAP NW Business Client 5]

How do I change the code to make it suitable for both SAP GUI and the SAP NW Business Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 
   `Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")`
I used 
    `Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUISERVER")` 
And this made my code work on Neveawer.